# Very slow updating in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, updates, performance

Every time I start eclipse (Whether my computers been on for 2 hours or 1 minute) the update speed is significantly slower than normal. What I mean by that is if I have something such as a paint method, the updates are very slow and painting things onto the screen at a much slower rate.

This usually stops after a short period of time, but can sometimes last for an hour or more. Iv'e searched the net for this, but can't seem to find anything. I've had this problem with both my desktop and laptop.

Does anyone else experience this problem? I was thinking it might have something to do with plugins but I'm not entirely sure. Any suggestions on a fix or possibly an explanation?

Comment: Sorry, if I create a paint method that is being updated by an ActionListener

Answer (score 0):

You need to see which processes are running at the same time and note their cpu and memory use.

on windows this is cnlt-alt-delete
on unix it is ps -au and variants

also note network usage.

you may have a background process, wanted or unwanted that is hogging resources.

Comment: Well that was my initial thought, but I didn't think that would be the issue for me... I have an i7 3370k, 16GB of ram and a new installation of windows 7, only 42 processes

Comment: I swear this has to be an eclipse/jre thing

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your eclipse installation, with the command line `eclipsec.exe -clean`:

> The easiest way to fix up a dusty workspace is using the -clean command line argument to the eclipse.exe executable.

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html